# Remove help_text from django UserCreationForm

Tags: python, django

I am making registration page but I don't like  text under username like :
`Required 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only`.
or under password:
`Your password can't be too similar to your other personal information.`
you get the point
pls help,thankyou

I tried to find other questions but they all remove help_text from  added field as email, but I need to remove from username,password...

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):

    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email' , 'password1', 'password2']
```

and then i render it in html as crispy form

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <fieldset>
        <legend class="hello4">
               <i>Join Today</i>
        </legend>
<div >
{{form|crispy}}

</div>
    </fieldset>
    <div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light">Sign Up</button>
    </div>


</form>
```

Comment: Could you tell precisely if you want to only remove the text, or disable the validation logic too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try edit class Meta as below::

```py
class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email' , 'password1', 'password2']
        help_texts = {
            'username': None,
            'password1': None,
            'password2': None,
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just don't want to show them on the page,
You can just get rid of them using css:

```css
.helptext {
    display: none;
}
```